# C# and ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

//Javascript function

function SaveAndUpdateProjectMaster() {

```
            var CompanyCode = '';
            var ProjectName = '';
            var ProjectDescription = '';
            var ProjectType = '';
            var LocationSite = '';
            var Client = '';
            var Latitude = '';
            var Longitude = '';
            var Status = '';
            var FirstLevelApprover = '';
            var SecondLevelApprover = '';
            var ThirdLevelApprover = '';
            var userComment = '';
            var CrudType = '';
            var Id = '';


            //$('#ddlDivision').val();
            //$('#ddlRegionPrm').val();
            //$('#ddlCountryPrm').val();
            Id = $('#HdxtProjectId').val();
            CompanyCode = $('#ddlCompanyPrm').val();
            ProjectName = $('#txtProjectnamePrm').val();
            ProjectDescription = $('#txtProjectDescriptionPrm').val();
            ProjectType = $('#ddlProjecttypePrm').val();
            LocationSite = $('#TxtLocationPrm').val();
            Client = $('#TxtClientPrm').val();
            Latitude = $('#TxtLatitudePrm').val();
            Longitude = $('#TxtLongitudePrm').val();
            Status = $('#hdnPMStatus').val();
            FirstLevelApprover = $('#TxtFirstLevelPrm').val();
            SecondLevelApprover = $('#TxtSecondLevelPrm').val();
            ThirdLevelApprover = $('#TxtThirdlevel').val();
            userComment = $('#txtUserComment').val();
            CrudType=$('#hdnBtnType').val();

            var obj = {};

            obj.Id = Id;
            obj.CompanyCode = CompanyCode;
            obj.ProjectName = ProjectName;
            obj.ProjectDescription = ProjectDescription;
            obj.ProjectType = ProjectType;
            obj.LocationSite = LocationSite;
            obj.Client = Client;
            obj.Latitude = Latitude;
            obj.Longitude = Longitude;
            obj.Status = Status;
            obj.FirstLevelApprover = FirstLevelApprover;
            obj.SecondLevelApprover = SecondLevelApprover;
            obj.ThirdLevelApprover = ThirdLevelApprover;
            obj.userComment = userComment;
            obj.CrudType = CrudType;


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "ProjectMaster.aspx/SaveAndUpdateProject",
                //data: JSON.stringify({ Id:Id,CompanyCode: CompanyCode, ProjectName: ProjectName, ProjectDescription: ProjectDescription, ProjectType: ProjectType, LocationSite: LocationSite, Client: Client, Latitude: Latitude, Longitude: Longitude, Status: Status, FirstLevelApprover: FirstLevelApprover, SecondLevelApprover: SecondLevelApprover, ThirdLevelApprover: ThirdLevelApprover, userComment: userComment, CrudType: CrudType }),
                data: JSON.stringify({ Id: Id, CompanyCode: CompanyCode, ProjectName: ProjectName, ProjectDescription: ProjectDescription, ProjectType: ProjectType, LocationSite: LocationSite, Client: Client, Latitude: Latitude, Longitude: Longitude, Status: Status, FirstLevelApprover: FirstLevelApprover, SecondLevelApprover: SecondLevelApprover, ThirdLevelApprover: ThirdLevelApprover, userComment: userComment, CrudType: CrudType }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data != '') {
                        debugger;
                        data = $.parseJSON(data.d);


                        data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        $('#ProjectMasterModal').hide();

                        var divison = $('#ddlDivision').val();
                        var country = $('#ddlCountryPrm').val();
                        var company = $('#ddlCompanyPrm').val();
                        var project = $('#ddlProjMaster').val();
                        //var masterVal = $('#hdnPMStatus').val();
                        GetRecord(divison,country,company,project,1);

                        alert(data.Msg);
                        CancelWarningCategory();

                    }

                }
            });

        }
```

//C# WebMethod

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string SaveAndUpdateProject(string Id,string CompanyCode, string ProjectName, string ProjectDescription, string ProjectType,string LocationSite, string Client, string Latitude, string Longitude, string Status, string FirstLevelApprover, string SecondLevelApprover,string ThirdLevelApprover,string userComment,string CrudType)
        //public static string SaveAndUpdateProject(string Id)
        {

            //string CompanyCode=string.Empty;
            //string ProjectName=string.Empty;
            //string ProjectDescription=string.Empty;
            //string ProjectType=string.Empty;
            //string LocationSite=string.Empty;
            //string Client=string.Empty;
            //string Latitude=string.Empty;
            //string Longitude=string.Empty;
            //string Status=string.Empty;
            //string FirstLevelApprover=string.Empty;
            //string SecondLevelApprover=string.Empty;
            //string ThirdLevelApprover=string.Empty;
            //string userComment=string.Empty;
            //string CrudType=string.Empty;


            string res = string.Empty;
            UserMsg obj = new UserMsg();
            try
            {

                String Result = string.Empty;
                BLL_ManageProject BLLProject = new BLL_ManageProject();
                //if (btnProjectsave.Text == "Add New")
                //{
                if (CrudType == "Add New")
                {
                    SqlParameter[] paramSaveProject = new SqlParameter[19];
                    paramSaveProject[0] = new SqlParameter("@CompanyCode", CompanyCode);
                    paramSaveProject[1] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectName", Convert.ToString(ProjectName));
                    paramSaveProject[2] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectDescription", Convert.ToString(ProjectDescription));
                    paramSaveProject[3] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectType", ProjectType);
                    paramSaveProject[4] = new SqlParameter("@LocationSite", Convert.ToString(LocationSite));
                    paramSaveProject[5] = new SqlParameter("@Client", Convert.ToString(Client));
                    paramSaveProject[6] = new SqlParameter("@Latitude", Convert.ToString(Latitude == "" ? "0.00" : Latitude));
                    paramSaveProject[7] = new SqlParameter("@Longitude", Convert.ToString(Longitude == "" ? "0.00" : Longitude));
                    paramSaveProject[8] = new SqlParameter("@IsActive", Convert.ToInt32(Status));
                    paramSaveProject[9] = new SqlParameter("@FirstLevelApprover", Convert.ToString(FirstLevelApprover));
                    paramSaveProject[10] = new SqlParameter("@SecondLevelApprover", Convert.ToString(SecondLevelApprover));
                    paramSaveProject[11] = new SqlParameter("@ThirdLevelApprover", Convert.ToString(ThirdLevelApprover));
                    paramSaveProject[12] = new SqlParameter("@PageName", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Last());
                    paramSaveProject[13] = new SqlParameter("@Title", "Insert Project Master");
                    paramSaveProject[14] = new SqlParameter("@UserComment", userComment);
                    paramSaveProject[15] = new SqlParameter("@SystemComment", "");
                    paramSaveProject[16] = new SqlParameter("@Revision", 0);
                    paramSaveProject[17] = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Session["WindowsID"].ToString())) ? HttpContext.Current.Session["WindowsID"].ToString() : null);
                    paramSaveProject[18] = new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", System.DateTime.Now);
                    Result = BLLProject.SaveProjectMaster(paramSaveProject);
                    if (Result == "1")
                    {

                        obj.Code = "1";
                        obj.Msg = GlobalConst.strInsertSuccess;
                    }
                    else if (Result == "2")
                    {

                        obj.Code = "2";
                        obj.Msg = GlobalConst.strRecordExists;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        obj.Code = "0";
                        obj.Msg = GlobalConst.strInsertFaliure;
                    }
                }
                else if (CrudType == "Update")
                {
                    SqlParameter[] paramSaveProject = new SqlParameter[20];
                    paramSaveProject[0] = new SqlParameter("@CompanyCode",CompanyCode);
                    paramSaveProject[1] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectName", Convert.ToString(ProjectName));
                    paramSaveProject[2] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectDescription", Convert.ToString(ProjectDescription));
                    paramSaveProject[3] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectType", ProjectType);
                    paramSaveProject[4] = new SqlParameter("@LocationSite", Convert.ToString(LocationSite));
                    paramSaveProject[5] = new SqlParameter("@Client", Convert.ToString(Client));
                    paramSaveProject[6] = new SqlParameter("@Latitude", Convert.ToString(Latitude == "" ? "0.00" : Latitude));
                    paramSaveProject[7] = new SqlParameter("@Longitude", Convert.ToString(Longitude == "" ? "0.00" :Longitude));
                    paramSaveProject[8] = new SqlParameter("@IsActive", Convert.ToInt32(Status));
                    paramSaveProject[9] = new SqlParameter("@FirstLevelApprover", Convert.ToString(FirstLevelApprover));
                    paramSaveProject[10] = new SqlParameter("@SecondLevelApprover", Convert.ToString(SecondLevelApprover));
                    paramSaveProject[11] = new SqlParameter("@ThirdLevelApprover", Convert.ToString(ThirdLevelApprover));
                    paramSaveProject[12] = new SqlParameter("@ProjectId", Id);
                    paramSaveProject[13] = new SqlParameter("@PageName",HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Last());
                    paramSaveProject[14] = new SqlParameter("@Title", "Update Project Master");
                    paramSaveProject[15] = new SqlParameter("@UserComment", userComment);
                    paramSaveProject[16] = new SqlParameter("@SystemComment", "");
                    paramSaveProject[17] = new SqlParameter("@Revision", 0);
                    paramSaveProject[18] = new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Session["WindowsID"].ToString())) ? HttpContext.Current.Session["WindowsID"].ToString() : null);
                    paramSaveProject[19] = new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", System.DateTime.Now);
                    Result = BLLProject.UpdateProjectMaster(paramSaveProject);
                    if (Result == "1")
                    {
                        obj.Code = "1";
                        obj.Msg = GlobalConst.strUpdateSuccess;
                        //BindProjectGrid(ddlDivision.SelectedItem.Value, ddlCountryPrm.SelectedItem.Value, ddlCompanyPrm.SelectedItem.Value, ddlProjMaster.SelectedValue.ToString());
                        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + GlobalConst.strUpdateSuccess + "');", true);
                        //btnCancelProject_Click(sender, e);
                    }
                    else if (Result == "2")
                    {
                        obj.Code = "2";
                        obj.Msg = GlobalConst.strUpdateSuccess;
                        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + GlobalConst.strRecordExists + "');", true);
                        //btnCancelProject_Click(sender, e);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        obj.Code = "0";
                        obj.Msg = GlobalConst.strUpdateFaliure;
                        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + GlobalConst.strUpdateFaliure + "');", true);
                        //btnCancelProject_Click(sender, e);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var myActualType = typeof(ProjectMaster);
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + GlobalConst.strErrorMessge + "');", true);
                SecurLog.ErrorLogInfoSave(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["WuserCode"]), ex.Source, myActualType.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "1", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.Substring(ex.StackTrace.LastIndexOf(' ')), "1", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "SECUR", Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["ServiceCo"]));
                SecurLog.SendErrorMail(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["WuserCode"]), ex.Source, myActualType.GetType().Name, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "1", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.Substring(ex.StackTrace.LastIndexOf(' ')), "1", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "SECUR", Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["ServiceCo"]));
                obj.Code = "0";
                obj.Msg = ex.Message;
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
        }
```

In the above code a mentioned javascript function and C# webmethod the ajax call is not working, not showing any errors and not hitting the break point. please help me thanks in advance!!!!!!!!!!!!!

But the above is working with 5 parameters but not working and not showing any errors  where more than 10 parameters is passed to ajax call

please help me..........
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the error function to the Ajax call to see possible errors

Comment: The problem is that your Webmethod expects querystring parameters and you are sending an object. Because of this, the route is never hit.  Alpesh Vaghela's answer below should work.

Comment: Also the line where you are stringifying an object should just be `JSON.stringify(obj)` as you've already built it up previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please add model for the query string params

```
public class ProjectModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
        public string ProjectType { get; set; }
        public string LocationSite { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string FirstLevelApprover { get; set; }
        public string SecondLevelApprover { get; set; }
        public string ThirdLevelApprover { get; set; }
        public string userComment { get; set; }
        public string CrudType { get; set; }
    }
```

and pass model in action method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveAndUpdateProject(ProjectModel model)
{
// your business logic
// you can access model properties by model.Id, model.CompanyCode
}
```

Also, in ajax method, you need to change your obj object

```
var model= new Object();  
model.Id = $('#HdxtProjectId').val();
model.CompanyCode = $('#ddlCompanyPrm').val();
model.ProjectName = $('#txtProjectnamePrm').val();
// rest of the properties
```

And in Ajax method, update data to :

```
data: JSON.stringify(model),
```

Comment: ProjectMaster.aspx/SaveAndUpdateProject:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)